# Is there a way to find out where a css rule is coming from?

Tags: css

I've inherited an .asp website and had to update the pages to relocate forms in tables to the sidebar.

It's worked fine on all but one page which stubbornly refuses to accept my css and is taking values from who knows where.

I've tried debugging in Firefox/Chrome and even written rules in the head of the page but to no avail. Is there a tool for identifying this kind of thing? I'm no slouch with css but this is baffling me. I don't want to resort to javascript to fix this as I see it as a fundamental issue.

Is there a way to find out where a css rule is coming from?

Comment: check out firebug, "inspect with firebug"

Comment: Hi is the table that overflows the container your problem? If it is, it's not about css your problem.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Danko - if not css then what is the problem?

Comment: Hi look at this, you have a table with two columns. The button "Send Enquiry" is on one td with colspan=0, due to his width it causes the first column takes his size. When you change the colspan=2 it fixes the problem.

Comment: @Danko - thanks so much. I've been staring at this for so long and didn't notice that! I HATE taking over other people's sites!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may use web inspector in Chrome.

Right click on failing element and select inspect element.

You should end up with web inspector window with two sections: left is html nodes tree and right is styles and properties of selected node. Failing element should be selected already.

Next you need to expand "Computed Style" tab and look for offending style.

When found, you'll see small triangle to the left of style definition - it is clickable. On click it should expand list of selectors that affects this style for this element. You'll see url to css for each of this. Bingo.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've done all of this but the property has no triangle at the side. It's the width property I'm chasing down. It has a class of style4 which is declared in the head of the file but it should be 100px and it comes out as 218px.

Comment: @user2739763 : check if a max-width larger than 100px is applied. Or view the Style tab to see if the width is overwritten by another width rule or a width-property defined on the HTML-element

Comment: I don't have the triangle it's just greyed out

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by austin and Waterlink the **Computed styles** (or **Computed** in FF) tab can show the currently applied styles, and their origin.

However, the **Styles** tab is also very useful. Upon right-clicking "inspect" on an element, the Styles tab will show a Full list of all the active styles and overwritten styles related to the inspected element. (Shows them as they were written in the CSS. Not what is actually being rendered)
That way you can tell which styles were overwritten in which order. A style in your css could be overwritten from an inline style, user defined style, a later defined css file or a css rule of higher importance, or even a non-css-attribute such as width/height attributes directly on a HTML-element

The formatting shows the status for a style:

- normal text = active
- strike through = inactive since another style has overwritten it
- greyed out = identifier not applied. ( If you are inspecting the Style of a `<p>` element and the css identifier is `p, span` , then the `span` identifer would be greyed out)

Example:

[image: chrome debugger image]

In this image, the `color` property of  `#post a` is inactive. It has been overwritten by the `color` property in `#cashieCatalog`.

Answer (score 1):

In the `HTML` tab of Firebug, you should see a panel on the right with tabs `Style`, `Computed`, `Layout`, and `DOM`.  Select `Computed`.  This will show you the "current" style being applied to the page.

If you expand a rule node, you should see a link on the right showing you which style sheet it is coming from, along with stylesheet rules that are being overridden.