# Disabling CSS transition in element

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition, effects

I've been trying to find where a hover transition has been added in a WP theme so I can customize/disable the effect but I can't seem to find it. Can you help?

The website is here: http://www.thisisutil.com/journal/ The effect I want to customize/disable is the hover effect on the post images.

Comment: use your document inspector

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find out where a css rule is coming from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496504/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-where-a-css-rule-is-coming-from)

Comment: @happymacarts I have been using the inspector but didn't know the tricks that Chris Happy showed below. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: offending code]

I found this by starting at the image and keep adding hover attributes until I see it pop up.

Another tool that could help you is the animation drawer:
[image: animation drawer]