# How to style Form

Tags: php, css, forms, laravel

I have a form in Laravel. I want to change the width of the form, because I want to put a other form next to it.

[It looks like this](https://ibb.co/j08XCw)

Which codes I should use in app.css? Any Suggestions? I tried codes in app.css but, maybe I should give a ID to form?

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => 'BusinessController@buy_energy']) !!}
<img src="images/foods/1.png" width="80px" height="80px"><br>   
{!! Form::label('number', 'Ekmek(1 adt = 7 TL): ') !!}
{!! Form::number('number', 'value', ['min'=>1, 'max'=>10 ]) !!}     
{!! Form::submit('Satın Al', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
```

Comment: Please post your code, not pictures of your code.

Comment: take an HTML/CSS 101 course, you'll see it'll pay off

Comment: added code, I know some info about styling but I just cant easily change the width of this form. thank you @GONG .

Comment: @Berke — Why can't you easy change the width? What's stopping you? Do you not know about the CSS `width` property? Are you having trouble writing a selector?

Comment: "I tried codes in app.css" — What codes? Show us a [mcve]

Comment: "maybe I should give a ID to form" — Maybe. Or maybe a class. Or maybe you can write a selector for the existing markup. There's no enough information in the question to tell what your problem is.

Comment: @GONG — While newbies are more likely to write low quality questions, being a newbie doesn't make the question higher quality.

Comment: @Berke — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496504/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-where-a-css-rule-is-coming-from

Comment: look guys I just ask a question, you can give an example how would you do it in your case. Imagine there is a form, which has a default width but you want to change it somehow, so how would you do it? just tell me these please with easiest example without making yourself so tired to explain.

Comment: @Berke — "it in your case" — My case is not your case. "which has a default width" — Forms don't have a default width (unless you count `auto`). If they have a width then it is coming from some code you have already and you need to either replace or override that code, and the specifics of how to do that will depend on how it is set.

Comment: Like some answers are here so funny, like go take course etc. or to answer questions with another questions. Then lets take course for everything in life and shut down all websites to ask something. Anyways thank you for your explanations and link shares.

Comment: Even how you can expect to hear a "high quality question" from someone which is not expert in that area. So funny to think like this, like a student ask questions like a professor asks.

Comment: @Berke — We can expect people to write [mcve]s. The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) has lots of useful advice, such as "Don't ask about… Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)". It isn't about having a high level of baseline knowledge. It's about showing a bit of effort and bothering to explain your actual problem instead of asking people to explain things, from scratch, that are covered by an introductory tutorial on the subject.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin, and respect to you that you know how much people spend effort! Nice talent. You can write a book about it. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Berke — You seem to have missed the word "showing" in the phrase "showing a bit of effort".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your blade add in the form the 'class' just like you add the action and the method:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => 'BusinessController@buy_energy', 'class' => 'myForm']) !!}
<img src="images/foods/1.png" width="80px" height="80px"><br>   
{!! Form::label('number', 'Ekmek(1 adt = 7 TL): ') !!}
{!! Form::number('number', 'value', ['min'=>1, 'max'=>10 ]) !!}     
{!! Form::submit('Satın Al', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
```

In your Css customize the myForm class:

```
.myForm{
   with: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally someone gives a useful simple example for newbies who asks "low quality" questions. THANK YOU! It works and I try many new things with this simple example.