# Where can i find the CSSinJS style i have written in the React component while inspecting browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-in-js

I have created a react style component which is flused to the brwoser as given below

```
<a href="#" role="tab" aria-selected="true" class="css-ed5ehc">
  <div class="css-1nrs7xj">
     Implementation
  </div>
</a>
```

Where can i see the actual css style for the class **"css-ed5ehc"** and **css-1nrs7xj** in the inspect DOM tree ?

I can see the style in the styles tab while inspecting, but not sure from where it is coming from. It just displays  in developer tool

[image: style without link]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Chrome web tools generally displays the filename that originates a CSS rule in the styles tab.

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496504/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-where-a-css-rule-is-coming-from), you can also click the file name in the "style" tab. You might need to prettify the CSS if you're viewing something in production, and you might need to enable sourcemaps if you're say, using webpack or the like in local development.

(It's also possible that in lieu of a filename, it'll display "`inline`" for this case. That should redirect you to the HTML element that might be `scoped` to this particular CSS-in-JS.)

[image: Where CSS Style Lives]

Comment: This is CSS in JS, so there is not link to the file. I have edited the question to accommodate this case